# Using Nginx, how can I get other computers on the same wifi network to see a subdomain?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dns, subdomain

How can I get other computers on the same wifi network to see a subdomain?

The issue:
I'm currently running a docker implementation on a server computer on a wifi home network. When I visit the subdomains on that server computer I'm able to see the assigned containers load. However, when I visit the subdomain from a different computer on the same wifi network, it cannot find the server at all. When I visit the primary domain, I see the computer.

Assumptions:

1. There is a DNS issue?
2. There is a miss-configuration in the non-server computers host file?
3. Miss-configuration on the ASUS Router?

Server and Router:
Mac OS XI Server. ASUS Router.

Host file Server:

```
127.0.0.1 hub.local
127.0.0.1 container1.hub.local
127.0.0.1 container2.hub.local
```

Host file Other PC:

```
[SERVER_NETWORK_IP] hub.local
[SERVER_NETWORK_IP] container1.hub.local
[SERVER_NETWORK_IP] container2.hub.local
```

Composer file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  proxy:
    image: 'jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest'
    container_name: proxy-test
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
      - './nginx-proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-proxy.conf:ro'
    networks:
      - default
  container1:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: container-1
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: container1.hub.local
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    networks:
      - default
  container2:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: container-2
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: container2.hub.local
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    networks:
      - default
  default:
    container_name: default
    image: nginx
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: hub.local
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
    volumes:
      - './src:/var/www/'
      - './webnginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx-proxy.conf

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     container1.hub.local;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container-1;
    }
}

server {
    listen        80;
    server_name     container2.hub.local;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://container-2;
    }
}

server {
    listen        80;
    server_name     hub.local;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://default;
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions to improve this implementation are welcome.

Comment: what's the primary domain ? does telnet SERVER_NETWORK_IP 80 work ?

Comment: @DefSoudani Not sure about telnet portion of it, but the main domain is hub.local. I'm almost 99.99% sure at this point in time it is a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to a fellow named Pokey via bitmerge. There was an issue with the /etc/hosts file entries. Explicitly adding in each subdomain in association with the server's network IP was needed. I used ifconfig to find the IP address of the server.

Example:

```
192.0.0.4 container1.hub.local
```